# How to make html elements move up/ down as image height resizes using only css and html

Tags: html, css, dynamic, responsive-design

All of the research I have done finds results on getting an image to resize, I have that.  I need the html elements to shift up and down as the image height changes.

I have a foreground header image that resizes depending on screen width.

> i.e. width: 100%; height: changes;  (This works)

The problem I have run into is that the html elements below the image do not change position (move up and down) as the image resizes. I can only use CSS and HTML.  I do not need to worry about IE compatibility.

I am including all CSS to make sure you have what you need, but I think header, picture, img, .main, .pc, and .mobile would be the only tags/classes with potential impacts.  Also, all of the relevant HTML.

CSS

```
    <style>
    html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, fieldset, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, form, label, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-family: Arial, Sans-serif;
    color: inherit;
}
body {
    line-height: 1.2;
    font-size: 80%;
    background-color: #BEBEBE;
}
.wrapper {
    max-width: 710px;
    min-width: 710px;
    border-top: 5px solid #ffb500;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #351C15;
    color: #FFF;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
a:hover {
    color: #ffb500;
}
.margin1 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
header {
    max-height: 200px;
    min-height: 190px;
    min-width: 480px;
}

.htable {
    z-index: 99;
    top: 10px;
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 300%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px 30px;
}
.htr {
    display: table-row;
}
.htd {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
picture {
    top: 5px;
    position: absolute;
}
picture img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 480px;
}
.main {

}
section {
    font-size: 150%;
}
.pc {
    margin: 0 30px;
}
.mobile {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
select {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 110%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #bebebe;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    background: transparent;
    padding-right: 27%;
    left: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.select-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    max-width: 250px;
    height: 37px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #fff;
}
.select-wrapper:before {
    content: url(/img/E210_wedge_down_32_white.png);
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 1px;
    width: 41px;
    height: 35px;
    background: #457508;
    speak: none;
    line-height: 2.3;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    right: 0;
}
label {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.button {
    border: .1em solid #003436;
    background-color: #457508;
    overflow: visible;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 100%;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    padding: 10px 15px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.button:hover {
    background-color: #58930a;
}
footer {
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 85%;
}
li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0px 2px;
}
 @media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
select, label, input, .select-wrapper, span {
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}
.wrapper { min-width: 480px;}
.pc {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
.mobile {
    padding: 0 30px;
    visibility: visible;
    position: initial;
}
.mobile .select-wrapper {
    max-width: none;
}
footer {
    padding: 0 30px 10px 30px;
}
.htable {
    top: 130px;
}
 }
</style>
```

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    <div class="htable">
      <div class="htr">
        <div class="htd"> <a href="repl_href"><img height="69" width="62"alt="logo" src="img/logo2.png" ></a></div>
        <div class="htd">
          <p>My Choice</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <picture>
      <source srcset="img/hero_landscape.png" media="(max-width: 480px)" />
      <img src="img/hero_pc.png" alt="Big Picture" width="710" height="200">
    </picture>
  </header>
  <!-- content -->
  <div class="main">
  <section class="pc">
    <form action="#top" name="frmCountry">
      <label for="countryList" class="margin1">Select your location:</label>
      <span class="select-wrapper margin1">
      <select id="coutyrList" name="dropdownList">
        <option value="repl_href">Schweiz - Deutsch</option>
        <option value="repl_href">United Kingdom - English</option>
      </select>
      </span>
      <input type="button" value="Go" class="button margin1" onClick="javascript:submitContent('frmCountry')">
    </form>
  </section>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: what is the resolution for the 480px image?

Comment: the resolution is 480x135px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the other answer states, your problem is the use of absolute positioned items.

http://jsbin.com/maniyojucu/edit?html,css,output

namely, the `picture`:

```
picture {
    top: 5px;
    /* position: absolute; */
    position: relative;
}
```

absolute items are removed from normal DOM flow, so the picture container does not have the same height as the picture.

You'll have to restructure your CSS/markup a bit to get your desired affect but my fiddle will point you in the right direction.

Comment: Changing from absolute to relative or static stops the image from resizing and moves the image vertically below the header text instead of below on the z-index. Though if that is the only way, I will look into a way to rework it to fix the other issues.

Comment: If you want to use absolute, then you will need to find a way to offset your form from the header. The header is not as tall as the picture because you used absolute positioning so you need a way to offset the form. You could just use `top: xxx` where x is a value, but it wont be responsive since the value is hardcoded. Maybe try a percentage.

Comment: Yeah, that is where I am now.  Is there a way to set .main to a percent using the img as the ratio?

Comment: Without javascript? not really. That's why it's in your best interest to find an alternative way to do what you're trying to do. I recommend using css background-image property instead of the image tag in your markup, and then style the header directly with percentages. it'll be responsive that way and stay in the document flow.

Comment: That is beautiful.  I'll try that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have this problem because your image is positioned absolutely which removes it from the normal flow allowing the other elements to rise up into its place. To see this, change that to `position:static` or remove it altogether, and it goes away except the page may not behave as you want.